# MongoDb configuration

Tags: mongodb-atlas

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: The connection string 'mongodb+srv://<hidden>@<hidden>/?retryWrites=true&25w=majority' contains an invalid '%' escape sequence.
```

Im trying connect my squidex 7.5 image to mongdb database in atlas mongodb. how to fix that connection string?

Comment: Here is your problem.
'%'    you need to terminate the use of that character I suspect.  This is weird because in MySQL that character is allowed AND is used to search for LIKE strings.  But in MySQL, / handles like this and you have to send a pair of // to terminate the use of that character, so i wonder if the same thing applies here.  But when the error code talks about escaping, that is what it means.  I realize this post is for mongo, but just comparing.

Comment: ok but that connection string is what im getting from mognodb atlas to access my database.

Comment: Well that is strange, but being I can't see how it is formatted because its likely part of the hidden elements, I don't know what happened there.  But, have you tried terminating the use of the character (double it up most likely) so that it is able to pass that character?  What is happening is that character is being passed but it never finds the second one so it assumes it got left open and so it terminates.   In the way that a quote or double quote needs another quote to encapsulate something, without the second one, the code doesn't know what to do.